# What is the Python test file type and identifiers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am reading this article: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

I know that a python file (.py) is a module. A folder with an `__init__.py` file is a package. A folder without an `__init__.py` file is a namespace package.

I am confused with below statement from the link:

> In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files
>   must be modules or packages (including namespace packages) importable
>   from the top-level directory of the project (this means that their
>   filenames must be valid identifiers).

What does "all of the test files must be modules or packages" and "importable from the top-level directory of the project" mean?

Answer (score 0):

As you have quoted in your own question, the file names of all test files must be valid [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). That is because:

> Test discovery loads tests by importing them.

Answer (score 0):

Python test files are normal .py files. You can have discoverability by separating the source code from your test code. There are many ways to do that.

Some standards usually apply here. People usually have a separated `tests` folder so you can run commands like:

`python -m unittest`
`coverage run --omit="*/tests/*" -m unittest discover`

I think, one example project can help you, here you are: 
https://github.com/staticdev/humanizer-portugues/